# Is there a way to have a dynamic for loop in c++?

Tags: c++, loops

So I am working on a project that requires me to do a simulation. The problem is that the number of simulations needed to be done depends on the result of the previous simulation. Its a bit like recursion, except there is no function to be called. The simulation for the first one is done by a for loop. That gives a number. Then, I need to repeat that simulation, until that number is 0.

Its better to just show the code then try to explain it I guess.

```
for(int i = 0; i < newnumber; i++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       //some probability loops
       newnumber++;
    }
}
//don't worry, I have some math that will make the new number 
// go down over time so the loop will eventually come to a stop
```

If I have a problem like this, how would i go about doing this? I can already see the questions being why would you want to do this and the answer is, I need to do a disease spread simualtion. When one person gets infected, they have the possibility to infect another person. where I have written newnumber++, I also have some probablity loops written. The percent to get infected is low so the loop isn't garuenteed to expand, but if it does, i need to run the probability function again for the person that gets infected since now they have the probability of infecting someone else. How would I go about doing something like this?

I tried a do while loop, but that just kept giving me an infinite loop so I am not sure how to fix a problem like this.

Comment: Yes this works. Have you tried running this before asking the question? If you're running in an infinite loop, you are probably not putting in the correct loop termination logic. Try running the code using a debugger and setting breakpoint at the newnumber increment to see when it's being incremented.

Comment: The logic here is sound, but I think you have a code issue.  you are using `i` for both the outer and inner loops, which is likely to cause issues.

Comment: I have two suggestions, 1) counter for inner and outer loop should have different variable name, 2) instead of **newnumber++** write it with **newnumber--**

Answer (score 1):

You can of course change the value of any (non-`const`) variable, no matter whether it's used in the condition part of a `for` loop or not.  Thus *yes*, you *can* have a `for` loop like that.

**But I'd advise against writing such a `for` loop.**  A `for` loop is typically used in situations when something must be repeated for a known (at the time the loop starts) number of times.  Changing the condition like you suggest requires tracking any changes to the used variables inside the loops body, and this can be a debugging nightmare.

You can state your intent more clearly with a `do {} while` loop.  [Example](https://ideone.com/ogSuyp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

constexpr int INITIALLY_INFECTED = 42;
constexpr double INFECTION_RATE = 0.8;

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    int newlyInfected = INITIALLY_INFECTED;
    int totalInfected = 0;
    do {
        totalInfected += newlyInfected;
        newlyInfected = std::binomial_distribution<>(newlyInfected, INFECTION_RATE)(gen);
        std::cout << "New infections: " << newlyInfected
            << "\ntotal now: " << totalInfected << std::endl;
    } while (newlyInfected > 0);
}
```

This allows you to state the intent more clearly:

> [..] i need to run the probability function again for the person that gets infected since now they have the probability of infecting someone else [..]

Here you say that whether a new simulation run is made depends on whether there's some (newly) infected person.  `newlyInfected > 0` pretty much states this.  `i < newnumber` does not.